# App Downloading web page not working

Tags: java, android, html, download

I am learning android development and in a tutorial i am following demonstrated how to download a web page and print it into logs with AsyncTask class but the problem is, app is hanging ( ui elements not appearing neither in emulator nor in my phone ) and when the ui elements appear ( after a long time say 5 minutes) the html source in log is not showing

***here is the code***

```
package com.example.slimshady.downloadhtml;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... buttoks) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            String result = "";

            // try catch for if malformed url
            try {
                url = new URL(buttoks[0]);

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while(data != -1)
                {
                    char current = (char)data;
                    result+=current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return  result;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failed";
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        try {
            String content = downloadTask.execute("https://www.google.com").get();
            Log.i("returned STring", content.toString());
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**everything seems ok but still no html source logging and what can be the cause for the ui elements appearing alot later than they should ? i mean the whole reason for an AsyncTask is that they run independent of the main thread so the ui elements are not effected by the task am i right ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is , you are invoking [`get`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) which will block your thread until you get the response so simply use

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    new DownloadTask().downloadTask.execute("https://www.google.com");
}
```

and update UI in `onPostExecute`

You can also improve the code using `StringBuffer` and `BufferReader` as

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... buttoks) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            String result = "";
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(); 

            // try catch for if malformed url
            try {
                url = new URL(buttoks[0]);

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                if (is != null) {                            
                    while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                        buf.append(result);
                    }                
                }

                return  buf.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failed";
            }

        }

        @Override
        ... onPostExecute(String str){
                // update UI here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding!